# 画面遷移の際のメモリの解放

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

NavigationControllerで画面遷移(A→B)をしています。

Aの画面にはテーブルビューで複数行セルがあります。
Bの画面にはコレクションビューで画像(写真)を並べています。
(BににはAで選択されたセルごとにB,B',B",...とそれぞれ異なる画像を並べています)

例えば、画面をA→B→A→B’と遷移するときに、メモリが画面遷移の度に増え続けてしまい減りません。
B→A→B’のときにBの画面のオブジェクトを解放するべきなのでしょうか。
そのようにすればメモリ使用量を減らすことができるでしょうか。

また、解放するときは画面が消えたとき
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
ここで解放すれはよいのでしょうか。

その際は、どのように解放すればよいのでしょうか。
メモリが増えてしまいパフォーマンスが遅くて困っています。

初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `Navigation Controller`は、スタック状の画面遷移なので、「B→A」のときに、Bは、`View Controller`ごと解放されるはずです。解放されないのは、BからAに「戻」っておらず、新しいAをスタックに積んでいるものと推測されます。あるいは、AとBの間で、参照の循環が起きているかです。とにかく、循環参照に気をつけて、教科書どおりに編集していけば、適切にメモリ解放されるはずです。